# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning Selenium, and I have Chrome version **61.0.3163.100** and ChromeDriver version **2.34.522940**. I tried this code:

```
public void adminLogin(){
        driver.findElement(By.name("userId")).sendKeys("sysadmin");
}
```

My page is getting loaded, but the *username* field is not getting populated with "sysadmin". This is the error I am getting:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1) on port 31275
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Feb 27, 2019 11:16:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'DWA7DEVOS00170', ip: '10.96.162.167', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\rajos1\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 61.0.3163.100, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: ff3cf91166eddfe1667f931b18ede2ea
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:100)
        at pulse.tpr.LoginInterface.adminLogin(LoginInterface.java:24)
        at pulse.tpr.LoginInterface.main(LoginInterface.java:34)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is all your code for the script?  Could you upload the HTML of the page you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Actions` class to first focus on element before using `sendkeys()` as shown below:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("userId")));
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys("sysadmin");
actions.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue. You are using an outdated version of chromedriver. Update the chromedriver to the latest version and set the webdriver property accordingly.

```
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
String path_to_driver = "C:\\blah\\blah\\chromedriver.exe"
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path_to_driver);
```

Next, you will be needing to upgrade your selenium library to the latest version as Selenium as backward incompatibility issues with Chromedriver.

> - Latest Selenium version is ***3.141.59***
> - Latest Chromedriver version is: ***73.0.3683.20***

ChromeDriver download link: [Download Chrome Driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Selenium download link: [Download Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

> **Note:**
>
> Make sure you wait for some time after you navigate to the
>   intended URL. Reason being, elements get populated in HTML DOM after a
>   certain time lapse. In case, the webdriver traverses the DOM during
>   this time, the driver.findElement() will fail to fetch the web element.

```
webdriver.get(url);
WebDriverWait wait_time = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DWA7DEVOS00170', ip: '10.96.162.167', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to **focus** on the *desired element*.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.34*
- You are using *chrome=61.0*
- But your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_25** which is pretty **old** and **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u25* , *ChromeDriver v2.34* and the *Chrome Browser v61.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u201**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

---

### Additional Considerations

As per best practices,

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* version to current ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.